# Weird behaviour of the code

Tags: c++

I saw that a part of my code did not work as expected. It does not go into the `if` statement and give an error while it should. I tried to examine the code and found something very odd. When I add `cout << i` in the for loop to check, it starts to work well. Can anyone explain what is the problem with it? Note: `airports` is a `vector` of Airport objects. `Airport::getName()` returns its name as `string`.

```
string name = "smth";
//this is the loop with unexpected behaviour
for (int i = 0; i < airports.size(); i++)
{
    //when the following line is taken outside the comment, it works well:
    //cout << i;
    if (isEqualNoCaseSense(name, airports[i].getName()))
    {
        cout << "Could not create airport " << name << ". It already exists." << endl;
        return;
    }
}
```

The function I used to compare strings without case sensitivity:

```
bool isEqualNoCaseSense(string str1, string str2)
{
if (str1.size() != str2.size())
    return false;
char *lowerStr1 = new char[str1.size()];
char *lowerStr2 = new char[str2.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < str1.size(); i++)
{
    lowerStr1[i] = tolower(str1[i]);
    lowerStr2[i] = tolower(str2[i]);
}
if (strcmp(lowerStr1, lowerStr2) == 0)
{
    delete[] lowerStr1;
    delete[] lowerStr2;
    return true;
}
else
{
    delete[] lowerStr1;
    delete[] lowerStr2;
    return false;
}
}
```

**EDIT:** Correcting the compare function fixes it, but I still wonder why `cout << i` fixed it

Comment: Your `char` arrays are not null terminated (needed for `strcmp`). But you really don't need them anyway. Just search stackoverflow for case insensitive string comparison.

Comment: Oh-em-gee. Dat monstrous comparison function! just don't.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant can you focus on the question :))

Comment: Why not use `std::string` instead of allocating dynamic arrays by hand? Better still, why not just loop and compare `tolower(str1[i]) == tolower(str2[i])`?

Comment: @farukdgn ya, I pretty much did. if you have unnecessary complexity in ye ole code, it will break.

Comment: Right. Get rid of the manual memory management and the unnecessary second loop and the problem will go away (because you won't be using strcmp on unterminated strings, but that's a detail, basically simpler code is harder to screw up)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't terminated your strings, but if you just write a sensible function it will work correctly:

```
bool isEqualNoCaseSense(const string& str1, const string& str2)
{    
    if (str1.size() != str2.size())
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < str1.size(); ++i)
        if (tolower((unsigned char)str1[i]) != tolower((unsigned char)str2[i]))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

No unnecessary allocation, and only loops through the strings up to the first mismatch.

> **EDIT:** Correcting the compare function fixes it, but I still wonder why `cout << i` fixed it

Because the program had undefined behaviour, so anything can happen. Adding random, unrelated code might change the memory allocation patterns of the code, or cause the compiler to optimise it slightly differently. You'll go mad trying to reason about some kinds of undefined behaviour. Just avoid it.

Comment: Isn't there some health warning about using `tolower` with `char`? I remember having to deal with that the last time I answered this question...

Comment: @juanchopanza, yes, it should really be cast to `unsigned char`, but for known ASCII input the values won't be negative even if your `char` is signed. If the input strings could have characters >127 the cast is needed.

Comment: Speaking of warnings, you should declare `i` either as `size_t` or `std::string::size_type` because of a signed/unsigned mismatch or possible loss of data on 64 bit.

Comment: @Axalo, meh. If you have 2GB in both `std::string` variables then overflowing the loop variable is not your biggest problem. (And we weren't talking of warnings, you won't usually get a warning for passing a `char` to `tolower(int)`)

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp` expects NULL terminated strings. So you needed to reserve one more character for the `lowerStr1, lowerStr2` arrays and set the last character of each array to NULL. Failing to do so, created undefined bahaviour to your program.

But you could bypass all these issues if you use `strncmp` function passing `str1.size()` as the third argument, since you already check if the two strings have equal size:

```
if (strncmp(lowerStr1, lowerStr2, str1.size()) == 0)
```

Comment: This is just making a terrible and inefficient solution work. But the fixed code is still terrible and inefficient.

Comment: OK, but why does it work well when I add `cout << i;` ?

Comment: Because the program has undefined behaviour, anything can happen.

Comment: I think it's somehow unfair. The question wasn't about optimizing the code.

Comment: No, but as I said, if you just rewrite the code to not allocate unnecessary arrays then the undefined behaviour disappears anyway.

Comment: @JonathanWakely it works well when I add cout line and does not when I doesn't add it. I doesn't seem "undefined".

Comment: You don't understand what "undefined behaviour" means. "It seems to work sometimes" is a valid result for undefined behaviour. Doing something strange that mysteriously "fixes" the program and trying to rely on that is a terrible, terrible way to program. It will break again when you turn on compiler optimisations, or someone else removes the mysterious "fix", or just because it's a different day of the week.